# Selenium chromedriver stopped unexpectdly

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, junit4, selenium-chromedriver

when i run my test using chrome driver in java selenium web driver it closes automatically giving following error trace in j unit......can any one help ??

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (100, 19). Other element would receive the click: ... (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 73 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19
>   17:28:14' System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_05' Driver info:
>   driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Session ID:
>   bbf0423d63c2cd68f7a731535c746373  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:244)

Comment: Can you post some of your code both selenium and site? It will be easier to find out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to click something that is not clickable at the time the test is executed. This could happen when some CSS/Javasript animation hasn't finished or the element you're trying to click is not in the visible area of the window.

See Selenium [issue 2766](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766) especially [comment 27](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766#c27)